# imagefield won't validate

Tags: python, django, django-models

I moved a site to a mediatemple server using python 2.3, now ImageField won't work in the admin. Upon saving, validation gives the "not valid image" error.

checked:

- media_root and media_url are correct
- PIL contains jpg support
- upload folders set to 775
- image is not corrupted

Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What version of Django are you running?

Answer (score 1):

If you read documentation here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/install/
You will find the answer.

> It works with any Python version from
>   2.4 to 2.6!

And :

> Set up a database
>
> If you installed Python 2.5 or later,
>   you can skip this step for now.
>
> If not, or if you'd like to work with
>   a "large" database engine like
>   PostgreSQL, MySQL, or Oracle, consult
>   the database installation information.

I think that the problem is python 2.3 do you consider upgrade of it to 2.4, 2.5 or 2.6?